# WIX public properties displayed on the UI

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

We have an installer created using WIX.  As part of this install we would like to show the currently selected installation path.  I thought this would be much easier than it is, apparently.  I have tried using the a public property "INSTALLDIR" (I know we're not using Installshield, this value is a directory ID.)

`<Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="AcmeInc">`

I can also see where INSTALLDIR gets set when running the install

`MSI(EC:6C) Dir (target): Key: INSTALLDIR , Object: C:\Program Files\AcmeInc\`

but when I try to show this on the UI using a Text attribute I get "`...\.`" which doesn't even look to be a relative path.

I know there has got to be something simple I'm missing here.

Comment: Are you using a custom UI, or one of the Wix UIs?

Comment: Is there any record that INSTALLDIR change its value?

Comment: @Alexy:  When you ask if there is any record that INSTALLDIR changes its value.  If you mean during the install, yes.  I can see that in the log anytime I change the value.

Comment: Is there 2nd record in the log where the value of INSTALLDIR changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using WiX 3.5 and the `MajorUpgrade` element - the following should work (I usually use `APPLICATIONFOLDER` instead of `INSTALLDIR` - but they should be interchangeable).

First, let's set `ARPINSTALLOCATION` as described on http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2011/1/14/ARPINSTALLLOCATION-and-how-to-set-it-with-the-WiX-toolset

```
<SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" After="CostFinalize" />
```

Now lets set the selected installation folder to the *previous* installation folder, if one previously existed that is.

```
<Property Id="INSTALLDIR" Secure="yes">
    <RegistrySearch Id="FindInstallLocation"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED]"
        Name="InstallLocation"
        Type="raw"
        Win64="yes" />
</Property>
```

And during the UI sequence, we want this value to be set 'early'

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <AppSearch After="FindRelatedProducts"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Thanks for your answer, After="CostFinalize" was the key.  :)